# SwiftUI conforming to Hashable

Tags: swiftui

How can we make a SwiftUI object, Image, in particular, conform to Hashable protocol?

I know they conform to the Equatable protocol, so the main question would be how to get a Hash value, or use the `hash(into:)` function?

Comment: I suspect this isn't currently possible. What are you trying to do with its hash? Maybe there's another approach.

Answer (score 3):

> In Swift, conforming to the `Hashable` protocol is often just as easy as adding `Hashable` to your conformance list. However, if you have custom requirements, or use properties that don’t all conform to `Hashable`, it takes a little more work.

Here’s an example struct we can work with:

```
struct iPad: Hashable {
    var serialNumber: String
    var capacity: Int
}
```

> Because that conforms to the `Hashable` protocol and both its properties also conform to the `Hashable` protocol, Swift will generate a `hash(into:)` method automatically.
>
> However, in this case we can see that `serialNumber` is enough to identify each iPad uniquely so hashing capacity isn’t needed. So, we can write our own implementation of `hash(into:)` that hashes just that one property:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(serialNumber)
}
```

> You can add more properties to your hash by calling `combine()` repeatedly, and the order in which you add properties affects the finished hash value.

Swift uses a random seed every time it hashes an object, which means the hash value for any object is effectively guaranteed to be different between runs of your app.

This in turn means that elements you add to a set or a dictionary are highly likely to have a different order each time you run your app.

Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-hashable-protocol

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488765/consistent-binary-data-from-images-in-swift) may also be of help as well.

Comment: This explains how to hash in general, but how does it apply to something like Image which has no public properties? Most SwiftUI Views are like this.