# Clear Video exif or GPS information in a video file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to clear all exif and GPS data from a video file in iOS, there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589118/stripping-all-exif-data-in-objective-c) for image, but I can't really find any for a video file. Using the suggested answer for removing those information will render the video data as invalid.

```
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:@"/path/to/video.MOV"];
data = [self dataByRemovingExif:data];
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSString *tempVidPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/%@.MOV", uuid];
[data writeToFile:tempVidPath atomically:YES];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempVidPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

//The methods

- (NSData *)dataByRemovingExif:(NSData *)data{
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, NULL);
NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

if (source) {
    CFStringRef type = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
    size_t count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);
    mutableData = [NSMutableData data];

    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)mutableData, type, count, NULL);

    NSDictionary *removeExifProperties = @{(id)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary: (id)kCFNull,
                                           (id)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary : (id)kCFNull};

    if (destination) {
        for (size_t index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, index, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)removeExifProperties);
        }

        if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
            NSLog(@"CGImageDestinationFinalize failed");
        }

        CFRelease(destination);
    }

    CFRelease(source);
}

return mutableData;
}

- (void)video:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo{
    if (error)... //show alert
}
```

Is there any workaround for a video file? I wanted to remove especially the GPS information, private API solution is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this API from AVMetadataItemFilter.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataitemfilter/1387905-metadataitemfilterforsharing?language=objc